# React does not recognize the `fullWidth` prop on a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Getting this warning in console in my react app buit with CRA.

`index.js:1 Warning: React does not recognize the` fullWidth`prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase`fullwidth `instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.`

[Warning screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d4dr.png)

Tried replacing `fullWidth` with `fullwidth`. But giving error.

Comment: Checkout this: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/16156

Answer (score 0):

The error is exactly as it said. Since you're using a native HTML element ("input"), you should use a lowercase prop, hence full-width (remember that the camelCase is transformed into kebab-case). Try checking in your code whether the prop is used or not; if not, you can always remove it.